# Java JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError for static load

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I need to link a JNI dll to my Java app, this is the code:

```
static
    {
        System.load("c:\\boca\\java\\BocaWorld.dll");
    }
```

And this is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\boca\java\BocaWorld.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

I could solve putting all dlls into the JRE/bin folder, but why the first method doesn't work? I don't want to copy all dlls into JRE folder.

Comment: You could also have the DLLs on the classpath and load it from there.

Comment: Ok but if there are all dlls in that folder what can be the cause of unsatisfied link error?

Answer (score 0):

You've provided only the path to the single native library, all it's dependencies are searched under the predefined paths, not the path, you've set for concrete library. You can try to set `java.library.path` system property for your application, pointing to the folder, containing your native libraries. This property is used to locate the native libs.

You can set it via command line arguments, like:

```
java -Djava.library.path=<path_to_libs> <main_class>
```

Or via `System.setProperty`, like:

```
System.setProperty(“java.library.path”, “/path/to/library”);
```

Furthermore, you are able to skip the path to the lib, since you set this property, becase JVM will search for it under the path, you've set, so it could be like:

```
static
{
    System.setProperty(“java.library.path”, “c:\\boca\\java\\”);
    System.loadLibrary("BocaWorld.dll");
}
```

But don't forget, that `java.library.path` can contain some paths already, so you can add your new path with `;` as separator.